# Weird MySQL encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, arabic

I have a column in the pages table with arabic data.

If I do this...

```
@mysql_query( "select title from pages where web_id = '$id'" );
```

I get correct data, in arabic.

But if I call the same function again, in fact, it's in a loop, the second time it brings me garbage data. Looking something like this

```
"ØªÙ†Ø¸ÙŠÙ… Ø§Ù„Ø£ÙˆÙ‚Ø§Ù Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù…Ø© Ø§Ù‚Ø±Ø£ Ù‚Ø·Ø§Ø¹
```

Also, if before that query, I do either of this:

```
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
@mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'" );
```

I always get garbage data, even on first call. What's happening here?

Note that database, table and field collations are set to utf8_bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some random hints:

Try not use the `@` operator. It will suppress any error message.

You need to escape input parameters properly:

```
mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE web_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'");
```

You need to check the return value of `mysql_query()`:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE web_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'");
if(!$res){
    die('Could not fetch page title'); // See mysql_error() for error message
}
```

Make sure your PHP source code is saved as UTF-8. Any decent editor will allow you save as UTF-8 and will display current encoding in the status bar.

Check your table definition. MySQL allows to set per table and column encodings.

Set the connetion encoding with `mysql_set_charset()`.

Make sure the browser renders your page as UTF-8. In PHP, you can generate the appropriate HTTP header with:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: id is being escaped already. there is a return value. php code is being saved as utf-8. page is displayed with utf-8 encoding. and as i've already mentioned, i've tried mysql_set_charset()

Answer (score 0):

You should verify whether your field actually contains UTF-8 data.  Even if it's set to UTF-8 you may have imported data incorrectly or that data might be corrupt.  You can look at the specific byte stream using:

```
SELECT hex(myfield) FROM mytable;
```

If you've imported data you should note that the data file might have been interpreted as being in a different encoding - indeed it might even have been do.  You'd need to ensure that the file is correctly recognised, e.g.:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8 database < mydbbackup.sql
```